# Determining the number of sides of a regular polygon given an inscribed triangle

Tags: geometry

If triangle $ABC$ is inscribed in a circle where $\angle C=\angle B=4\angle A$. $B$ and $C$ are adjacent vertices of a regular polygon of $k$ sides inscribed in this circle. How do I $k$? I know the answer should be 9. Could someone direct me to a theorem or provide a path towards this answer.

Comment: Can you find the angle measures of $A,B,C$?

Comment: If you need help with quasi's question, remember that the sum of angles in a triangle is 180.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find $\angle A, \ \angle B, \ \angle C$ from the condition
$$
\angle A+ \angle B+ \angle C = 180^\circ.
$$
We have
$$
\angle A+4\angle A+4\angle A = 180^\circ, \qquad9\angle A = 180^\circ, 
$$
therefore
$$
\angle A = 20^\circ, \qquad \angle B= 80^\circ, \qquad \angle C= 80^\circ.
$$
Let point $O$ be the center of the circle.
Since $\angle A = \angle BAC = 20^\circ$ is an inscribed angle, the corresponding central angle $\angle BOC$ is twice as much, i.e. $\angle BOC=40^\circ$, by the [inscribed angle theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle). But $40^\circ$ is exactly $1/9$ of full circle, so $BC$ is a side of an inscribed regular $9$-gon (*regular nonagon*, i.e. regular polygon with $k=9$ sides).